# Best database design to hold custom attribute values against records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

In our system we can have custom attributes that the user can define against products. e.g. Products can have different attributes such as Make, Model, Colour, Size, TV Size, Release Date, Gender, Power Output, Manufacturer etc

To do this we have 3 tables as described below.

```
Product  
-Id  
-Name  
-Price  

Attribute  
-Id  
-Name  
-AttributeTypeId  

AttributeType  
-Id  
-Name
```

The AttributeType which acts as a lookup table, will only ever have 6 rows to determine the type of attribute [Single Line Text, Multi Line Text, Number Integer, Number Decimal, Date, DateTime].  This table won't change.

I am a database beginner and struggling to decide on what would be the best way to store attribute values against the products.  I can think of 3 approaches, but i am not 100% sure which would be best.

```
ProductCustomAttribute  
-Id  
-ProductId  
-AttributeTypeId  
-TextValue (NVARCHAR(MAX))  
-IntegerValue  (INTEGER)  
-DecimalValue  (DECIMAL)  
-DateValue  (DATETIME)  

ProductCustomAttribute  
-Id  
-ProductId  
-AttributeTypeId  
-SingleLineValue  (NVARCHAR(MAX))  
-MultilineValue  (NVARCHAR(MAX))  
-IntegerValue  (INTEGER)  
-DecimalValue  (DECIMAL)    
-DateValue  (DATETIME)  
-DateTimeValue  (DATETIME)  

ProductCustomAttribute  
-Id  
-ProductId  
-AttributeTypeId  
-Value (NVARCHAR(MAX), will hold value for all types)
```

Any advice would be great? My view is that option 1 or 2 would be best but can't decide how to choose from these 2.

I am leaning towards option 1 because although option 2 is more readable, it also means more columns.  Option 2 has a column for **every type of attribute** and Option 1 has a column for every **data type** available for the 6 attribute types.

Comment: Looks like you have tried to achieve maximum normalization. Take a step back and look at the nature of your inputs. Will the type of an attribute change at all? It sounds like it will, based on your design. But if it does not, then you can eliminate that last table for attribute type.

Comment: The AttributeType table won't change, it will always have 6 rows.  I put it in because i wanted to have a descriptive value in my design.

Comment: I'd actually go with the third option. It is probably only your UI that needs all the tables. When pulling data, option #3 will offer you better performance.

Comment: Cross post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154174/best-database-design-to-hold-custom-attribute-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If it's possible to model these attributes as just normal fields in your core data tables, do that.
2. If that's not possible because these extra fields are user-defined or otherwise can't be in your core design, try your approach #2 because: whenever possible, you want to define data types, constraints and rules in such a way that the database can enforce them, and the application doesn't have to redundantly interpret and enforce the types / constraints / rules.

Comment: Is approach 2 better because than 1 because the fields are more specific to the domain?  Therefore making it easier to add attribute type specific rules.  I am leaning towards this approach too,  the only downside i can think of is having 2 additional columns which will be null on every row (i am not too fussed about this though)

Comment: Agreed. When in doubt, be more specific.